# I want to perform classification on two different classes using training data but it won't work

Tags: classification

I've been trying to classify mangroves using training data consisting of 2 classes: 0 and 1. I tried using both SVM and smile forest classifiers and they just show the class labelled "1". So for example, I would add 15 polygons for each mangrove and non-mangrove areas. I'd label the mangrove areas as 1 and non-mangrove areas as 0. The final product only shows the color blue everywhere with no red at all. When I decided to switch the classes, the final layer became fully red meaning there's been only a loss of mangroves.

I didn't post the training data because I've added them manually so it's too long of a text.

Any ideas on how to move forward?

Here's the full code:

```
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')
  .median();


var calculateNDVI = function(image) {
//  var nirBand = image.select('B5');
//  var redBand = image.select('B4');
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};


var ndvi2010 = calculateNDVI(collection2010);

var ndviRegion2010 = calculateNDVI(ndvi2010.clip(geometry));


var visParams2010 = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
//p.addLayer(ndvi2010.select('NDVI'), visParams2010, 'NDVI 2010');
//Map.addLayer(ndviRegion2010.select('NDVI'), visParams2010, 'NDVI 2010 (Region)');



var collection2020 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
  .median();


var ndvi2020 = calculateNDVI(collection2020);
var ndviRegion2020 = calculateNDVI(ndvi2020.clip(geometry));
var visParams2020 = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
//p.addLayer(ndvi2020.select('NDVI'), visParams2020, 'NDVI 2020');
//Map.addLayer(ndviRegion2020.select('NDVI'), visParams2020, 'NDVI 2020 (Region)');

ar classifier = ee.Classifier.libsvm().train({
  features: trainingData,
  classProperty: 'class',
  inputProperties: ['NDVI']
});
var classified2010 = ndvi2010.select('NDVI').classify(classifier);


var classified2020 = ndvi2020.select('NDVI').classify(classifier);


var change = classified2020.subtract(classified2010);


Map.addLayer(change.clip(geometry), {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'white', 'blue']}, 'Change in Mangrove Distribution');
```